# winform - setting Selected value of listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I had a list box called listbox1 will bounded to list like this:

```
ValueVM word1 = new ValueVM { Id = 1, Name = "AAA" };
ValueVM word2 = new ValueVM { Id = 2, Name = "XBB" };
ValueVM word3 = new ValueVM { Id = 3, Name = "ACC" };
ValueVM word4 = new ValueVM { Id = 4, Name = "ACB" };
ValueVM word5 = new ValueVM { Id = 5, Name = "OTD" };
ValueVM word6 = new ValueVM { Id = 6, Name = "FDD" };

var li = new List<ValueVM>() { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6 };
listBox1.DataSource = li.OrderBy(l=>l.Name).ToList();
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I want to one Item to be seleted in this list box, suppose I want the Id=2;

```
int myID = 2;
//Idont know what the selected index will be but I need the selected value to be set
// I tried to set listBox1.SelectedValue=myId.ToString();
//but still returning null
listBox1.SelectedValue = myID;
```

**as mentioned in MSDN:**

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property. (Inherited from ListControl.)

my problem that seleted value get the value from value member but it didn't set the value?
any Ideas?

Comment: `Name` is a field or property? Fields doesn't support databinding

Comment: I use class ValueVm Like this `class ValueVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }` Im sure it's property :(

Comment: @Eddy4v your code event doesn't compile, the `li.OrderBy(l=>l.Name)` should be appended with `ToList()`. I still don't get what you want? running your code will select the `XBB` (with `Id=2`), isn't that what you want?

Comment: @KingKing this compiles but throwing runtime exception. You mean the same?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ah, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the right direction only. `SelectedValue` should do what you need.

```
listBox1.SelectedValue = 2;//this works for me
```

Note: You've to set the `int` here since datasource is `int`. setting "2" won't work

Comment: @KingKing Yes, Same But this works. May be OP is trying different and posted different. OP also stated `listBox1.SelectedValue=myId.ToString();` this doesn't work Of course this won't work. OP would have set it as string.

Comment: thank you Sriram Sakthivel , Nemanja Boric, Alessandro D'Andria it's works with no updated to my code!!! It's seemed that visual studio is missed up and when I reboot it worked!! why? I don't know!!!!

Comment: @Eddy4v SO strange. I suspect you'd have set "2". Is it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I tried the both actually and I know that both are working but it seemed that it's vs2010 fault!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
listBox1.SetSelected(MyId, true);
```

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx)

Comment: `SetSelected` accepts the index of the element and not the value.

Comment: as I mentioned before I don't want to select the index, SetSelected will assign my Id to the index of list-box which is different from my id

Comment: Why not use `listBox1.SelectedItem = li[myID];`?

Comment: thank you Sriram Sakthivel , Nemanja Boric, Alessandro D'Andria it's works with no updated to my code!!!
It's seemed that visual studio is missed up and when I reboot it worked!! why? I don't know!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should change yourcode  into someting like this

```
 listBox1.DataSource = li.OrderBy(l=>l.Name).ToArray();
```

because the datasource does not understand  IOrderedEnumerable

Hopethis help